# Understanding the usage of parameters passed inside $.each in plugin code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to jQuery and just learning new stuff. I was just reading through Chris Coyer's article and came across the following code :

```
$.fn.faq = function(options) {
    
    return this.each(function(i, el) {

      var base = el,
              $base = $(el);
          
          console.log(options);
      
      base.init = function() {
        // Do initialization stuff
            $base
               .find("dd")
               .hide()
               .end()
               .find("dt")
               .click(function() {
                 
                 var ans = $(this).next();
                 
                 if (ans.is(":visible")) {
                   base.closeQ(ans); 
                 } else {
                   base.openQ(ans); 
                 }
                 
               })
      };
      
      base.openQ = function(ans) {
        // Open panel
                ans.show();
        
        // Do callback
        options.qOpen.call();
      };
      
      base.closeQ = function(ans) {
        // Open panel
                ans.hide();
        
        // Do callback
        options.qClose.call();
      };
      
      base.init();
           
    });
  
};

$("dl").faq({
  qOpen: myQuestionOpenCallback,
  qClose: myQuestionCloseCallback
});

function myQuestionOpenCallback() {
  alert("answer opened!");
}

function myQuestionCloseCallback() {
  alert("answer closed!");
}
```

Now I didn't quite understand this part of the code:

```
return this.each(function(i, el) {
```

The second line in the code, what exactly is `i` and `el`? I don't see anywhere these parameters being passed into the each function.

I asked a senior colleague of mine and got the following answer:

> Many plugins start that way. Since most plugins are chainable, they
> have to return this. And they also have to loop through the elements
> from the selector,
>
> ```
> return this.each(function(i, el) {
> ```
>
> does them both. A loop, then the return.

but I still didn't quite understand.

The JS Fiddle can be found [here](http://jsbin.com/ekuxat/6/edit?html,js,output).

Comment: See [https://api.jquery.com/each/](https://api.jquery.com/each/). `i` and `el` are passed by jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside a jQuery plugin, `this` refers to the jQuery object representing what you called the plugin on. For example, in the case of this `faq` plugin, if I call `$('#someDiv').faq({ ... });`, `this` will be the same as `$('#someDiv')` inside the plugin function.

So because it is a jQuery object representing a selection of DOM nodes, you can call the jQuery method `.each()` on it, which takes a function that gets given two parameters when it is called for each DOM node in the selection:

1. The index (0, 1, 2 and so on)
2. The DOM node itself

`.each()` also returns the thing it was called on, so you end up returning the `$('#someDiv')` object from the plugin. That's great, because then we can call some other jQuery method on it straight afterwards ("chaining"). e.g. `$('#someDiv').faq({ ... }).hide();` to hide it immediately.

Comment: So it means that `el` represents each selected `this` in this case?

Comment: Think of it this way, if I have two `<div class="my-class">`s on my page and I call `$('.my-class').faq()`, the function you are talking about will get called twice. The first time `i` will be `0` and `el` will be the DOM node for the first div. The second time `i` will be `1` and `el` will be the DOM node for the second div.

Answer (score 1):

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

- i : index of the element.
- el : the DOM element (not a jQuery object).